# Jquery - Show divs one by one

Tags: jquery, html

I need to show many divs (created dinamically) one by one as the uses clicks the `previous` and the `next` label.

What I have tried:

HTML:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="panel_steps_page1" class="pages page1"> </div>
<div style="display: none;" id="panel_steps_page2" class="pages page2"> </div>
<div style="display: none;" id="panel_steps_page3" class="pages page3"> </div>
<div style="display: none;" id="panel_steps_page4" class="pages page4"> </div>

<span id="btn_previous" class="previous">previous</span>
<span id="Span1" class="next">next</span>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".page1").show();

$(".next").click(function(e) {
    $(".pages").each(function(index) {

        if ($(".page" + index).is(":visible")) {
            $(".page" + index).hide();
            $(".page" + (index + 1)).show();
        }
    });

});

$(".previous").click(function(e) {
    $(".pages").each(function(index) {
        if ($(".page" + index).is(":visible")) {
            $(".page" + index).hide();
            $(".page" + (index - 1)).show();
        }
    });
});
```

It's not working though.

**[Live jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umtMC/)**

Comment: why isn't it working?

Comment: @Liam the `previous` button does nothing and the `next` button displays immediately the very last div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is over-complicated. Here's a much simpler version that almost reads aloud the same as it works:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    $(".pages:visible").hide().next().show();
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
    $(".pages:visible").hide().prev().show();
});
```

The above is a good starting point, but it can end up hiding all of the divs if you try to step out of bounds. That problem can be fixed with a small tweak:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    $(".pages:visible").hide().next(".pages").addBack().last().show();
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
    $(".pages:visible").hide().prev(".pages").addBack().first().show();
});
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5LHJ/)**.

**Update:** Edited the code (but not the fiddle) to replace `.andSelf()` with `.addBack()`, based on insertusernamehere's comment below.

Comment: How can I handle the first and the last element? Because if I click `previous` when the 1st div is visible or `next` when the last div is visible all the divs disappear and nothing shows up anymore. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umtMC/1/

Comment: @enb081 look at my answer. There is solution of this problem

Comment: Thank you all. Because this answer is the least complicated and uses very few lines of code, this is the one i'm accepting.

Comment: +1 - As a note on `.andSelf()`: [This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later.](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Thanks, I had somehow missed that. Edited the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will keep you from hiding the last page or the first page.  It prevents the scenario where no page is shown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".page1").show();

    $(".next").click(function(e) {
        var next = $(".pages:visible").next(".pages");
        if(next.length >0){
           $(".pages:visible").hide();
           next.show();
        }
    });

   $(".previous").click(function(e) {
       var prev = $(".pages:visible").prev(".pages");
        if(prev.length > 0){
           $(".pages:visible").hide();
           prev.show();
        }
   });
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/envDx/1/

Comment: @enb081 glad I could help. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".next, .previous").click(function(e) {
    var $p = $('.pages:visible'), 
        m = this.className == 'next' ? 'next' : 'prev';
    if ($p[m]('.pages').length) $p.hide()[m]().show(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xMaZQ/

Answer (score 2):

I used another solution, more optimized because I avoid **each** iteration.

```
$(".next").click(function(e) {
    var shown = $(".pages.visible").hide().removeClass('visible');
    var index = (shown.index() + 1) % 4;

    $(".page"+index).show().addClass('visible');
});

$(".previous").click(function(e) {
    var shown = $(".pages.visible").hide().removeClass('visible');
    var index = shown.index();
    index = (index == 0)? 3: index - 1;

    $(".page"+index).show().addClass('visible');
});
```

Try my solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/NGVf5/4/) and let my know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, +1 for going from the last step back to the first one (not needed in my case though, but thanks anyways).

Answer (score 1):

There is your updated [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/umtMC/2/).

```
$(".next").click(function(e) {
    var $visibleOne = $(".pages:visible");
    var $nextToBeVisible = $visibleOne.next('div.pages');

    if($nextToBeVisible.length > 0) {
        $visibleOne.hide();
        $nextToBeVisible.show();
    }

});

$(".previous").click(function(e) {
    var $visibleOne = $(".pages:visible");
    var $PrevToBeVisible = $visibleOne.prev('div.pages');

    if($PrevToBeVisible.length > 0) {
        $visibleOne.hide();
        $PrevToBeVisible.show();
    }
});
```